# Export pb and pbtxt from python tensorflow to opencv with c++

Tags: opencv, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

Hello everybody i created my own model inside tensorflow 2.0 and i dont know how to export pb file and pbtxt to opencv can anyone tell me how

Thank you in advance

Comment: So you wanna use on c++ or python?

Comment: i want to use python to make my model then exporting it to opencv c++